# ObjectMapper - Desserialize flattened object

Tags: java, kotlin, jackson, objectmapper

I have the following class that uses internally a HashMap:

```
open class I18n<T> {

    var i18n: MutableMap<LanguageEnum, T?> = mutableMapOf()
        @JsonAnyGetter get

    fun add(lang: LanguageEnum, value: T?) {
        i18n[lang] = value
    }

    // ...
}
```

Thanks to the `@JsonAnyGetter` annotation, when I serialize this into Json I have the following format:

```
{
    "pt": "Texto exemplo",
    "en": "Example text"
}
```

instead of

```
{
    i18n: {
        "pt": "Texto exemplo",
        "en": "Example text"
    }
}
```

Now I need to make the way back. I have a HashMap containing the languages key and I need to desserialize it into my `I18n` object.

The caveat here is that I'm doing this among a lot of reflections and abstractions and it would be really nice if it could work like this:

```
// Here I am going through the fields of a given POJO. 
// One of those fields is a I18n type. 
// My model variable is a Map containing the same keys as my POJO field's name, so I'm basically trying to map them all
for (f in fields) {
    if (model.containsKey(f.name)) {

        // when f.type is I18n, value is a HashMap<string, string>
        val value = model[f.name]
        f.isAccessible = true

        // when f.type is I18n.class, the field is set to an empty instance of I18n because it could not desserialize
        f.set(dto, mapper.convertValue(value, f.type))
        f.isAccessible = false
    }
}
```

I would not like to do things like:

```
if (f.type === I18n.class) {
    // Special treatment
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.